# Setting a MP3 as ringtone android?

Tags: android

How can I make my app set a mp3 stored in the SD Card as a ringtone? my app uses android 2.1+?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. :)

http://www.ceveni.com/2009/07/ringtone-picker-in-android-with-intent.html